# How to dynamically calculate the positioning width of a fixed div element using the width of browser and width of the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, position

I'm using the following CSS Styling for two div's that will place skyscraper ad's on my website to the left and right of the body.

```
/*-----Sky Scraper ad----*/
#SkyAdLeft{
 width: 160px;
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
 left: 10px;
  height: 600px;
 z-index: 7;
}
#SkyAdRight{
 width: 160px;
  display: block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
 right: 10px;
 height: 600px;
 z-index: 7;
}
```

I want each DIV to remain fixed however I want to dynamically calculate the left position in the left ad and the right positioning in the right ad to be able to sit 10px left or right of the body.

With my body always being 980px and centered I figured out the math to do this based on browser width. My Ad's are 160px in width.

Width Calc for Left AD:

(Browser width - 980) / 2 = X

(Browser Width - (160 + X + 980)) -10

Width Calc for Right Ad:

(Browser width - 980) / 2 = X

(Browser width - X) +10

Calculations explained:  I am subtracting the body width of 980 from the dynamic browser width  then dividing by 2 to get the value of the empty spaces between the end of my browser and the end of my body. This is where the ads with sit.

The second calculation for each respective ad then calculates where the ad should be positioned within the browser screen.

The right ad is simple. It's the Browser width minus X which is the empty space value form the first calculation. Then add 10px. This will set the ad 10x to the right of the body.

The second calculation for the left ad is more complicated but also will set the left ad 10px to the left of the body.

How do I use jquery or javascript to do these calculations and where do I run the jquery? In the css styling file or in my footer.php file where the div's are in the code?

Also if anyone knows a quicker solution to this problem that will allow my div's to sit 10px left or right of the body. Please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand why you are calculating the browser/window width! With a `position:fixed` element, setting the `left:10px` or `right:10px` will be enough to place it. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: When it is fixed the left and right position goes by the browser window. So if there are different resolutions or different zoom's or if someone resizes the browser while in the page the ads will stay at the edge or if they resize it to be very small, the ads will go behind the body. All this looks very unprofessional and sloppy. I want the ads to be 10px form the body at all times no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the Ads to sit 10px away from the centered "container" (not the `body`).

If so, it's just a matter of positioning each ad 50% away from it's respective side and the adjusting the margins

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zHjso)

```
**HTML**

<div class="Ad left">

</div>

<div class="Ad right">

</div>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width:980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:500px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.Ad {
  width: 160px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  height: 600px;

}

.left {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-left: calc(-160px - (980px/2) - 10px);
  /* element width + 50 % of container width + required distance */
}


.right {
  right:50%;
  background-color: purple;
  margin-right: calc(-160px - (980px/2) - 10px);
}
```

Comment: Paulie_D! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Putting right and left at 50% then just setting margins worked like a charm! Exactly what I needed! I'm learning as I go and even though I am a newb I can't believe that this solution didn't come to me. I was trying to do something the hard way when a simple solution was right in front of me the whole time! Thanks man!

Comment: BTW I realized I didn't need to calculate anything once left and right was set to 50%. Then I just set margins for both to 500px. All complete! Thanks again!

Comment: I tired hitting the up arrow and it says I have to be reputation of 15 or higher. Is their another way to give you credit?

Comment: Dear Paulie_D I have used your method on my website: mpatika.hu , but the issue is that the height is not the given height, but its 100%. Can you help me with this? Thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest that you ask your own question **with appropriate code** so that we can see what we are dealing with.